# How to add a scroll to bootbox dialog?

Tags: javascript, bootbox

I have searched the web and I have failed to find a solution to adding a scroll to a bootbox custom dialog. Is there anyway I could get it to work. I need a vertical scroll.

Is this possible?

Comment: please add some sample code to your question, illustrating where you are stuck

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) uses a css class named `modal-body` for the body of its dialog; so you can override the class to make it scroll-able. For instance:

```
.modal-body {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: @kyadondotimothy, in a `style` tag in your page or in a css file that must be referenced in your page.

Comment: I found this to be slightly better when your dialog can contain different things: 

.modal-body {
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

That sets the maximum height, after which the scrollbar is added. So if you have little content, no bar and height adjusts to fix. If you have lots of content, you get a scrollbar and the height doesn't get too crazy high.

Comment: @Tundey your answer really help me in my project. I think you should post it as a different answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your dialog to expand and add scrollbars based on the size of your content, use this:

```
.modal-body { 
   max-height: 500px; 
   overflow-y: auto; 
}
```

That sets the maximum height, after which the scrollbar is added. So if you have little content, no bar and height adjusts to fix. If you have lots of content, you get a scrollbar and the height doesn't get too crazy high.